# how can i create comment in WordPress REST API (Version 2)

Tags: swift, wordpress, rest, post, comments

please help me

> how can i create `comment` in WordPress REST API (Version 2) with swift
>   programmatically ? with ( UIButton and UIText )

i know to GET comment ( **read comment** )

but i don't know how to send comment 
( from my app to my web in WordPress ) ( **POST** )

thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGv1H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From document [here](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/comments/), you need to do a POST request to the following URL

```
/wp/v2/comments
```

The parameters are like this

[image]

To do this, link a button click action to your code

```
@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Import Alamofire API to your project. This API is well adopted for http request. You can find instruction [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Finally do post request in this way. Put this code in the button action function above

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "author": "something",
    "email": "example@email.com",
    ...
]

Alamofire.request("UrlOfYourWebSite", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    // parse responseData.result.value
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend but , Can you give me an example? for post 1 comment

Comment: @user3325024 I do not have a server running their API. Do you have one?

Comment: @user3325024 Sorry I'm a bit confused here. Are you looking for swift code to post data to an url? Or you are looking for the url from your worldaps.net website?

Comment: i won't ( POST )=( SEND )  comment from my app ( in swift ) to my web ( https:// worldaps.net ) , i won't the complete code to do this .. with uibutton and uitext

Comment: @user3325024 you **won't** ? Or you want?

Comment: oooooh , iam soooory ,, i want  ,, i need that

Comment: @user3325024 Updated my answer. You need to try it. This site is not for us to write the entire thing for you. Let me know if you meet problem

Comment: After typing this code I have this error ،،، https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGv1H.png ،،، and I did not know where to write the comment in the code to send to the site

Comment: please help me 

Comment: @user3325024 Updated alamofire method.... You need to look at their documentations first... Comment in the API call is under parameter content from the document

Comment: @Fangming  thank you for the hint to past data to an url